linux ip rules for vrf VS ip rules for policy routing table
i have found my self a bit confused about how ip rules differ between VRF and policy routing table
     =============== policy routing table  part =============== 

here i have an example that is working for "policy routing table".
ip route add default via 192.168.10.200 dev vlan100 table 100

creates the policy routing table and add a default route to it.
ip rule add prio 100 from 10.10.10.10 table 100

creates the an ip rule that say that any packet that comes
to the system with source ip of 10.10.10.10 will be
looked up in table 100 and routed accordingly.
      ===============  vrf  part =============== 


ip link add vrf-10 type vrf table 10     # create a vrf  ( created the l3mdev)

ip link set dev vrf-10 up                # ( bring up the l3mdev device  )

ip link set dev vlan750 master vrf-10    #    add a link to a vrf

ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev vlan750    # set ip address to if in a vrf.

ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.10.10.254 dev vlan750 vrf vrf-10    # add def route

now the Q:
• is there a way to add ip rules to make traffic go to the vrf, if yes - plz show explain and elaborate = )
thanks for any time and help that will be done here !

What rules do you have after those commands? Usually a special rule pops up on its own.

•dont have any thing after those commands - what i shared is the full picture.
tho if u think that some thing is missing - let me know
•there are no any auto rules that are added by themself.

What is the output of ip rule at the end?

@u1686_grawity - nothing - i dont have the serve under my hand ... so cant say 100% tho i can say that i get the feeling that ip rules are used for PBR stuff and are not related to VRF's at all ...  will be gald to approve this assumtion.

VRFs on Linux work by adding a special PBR rule – plus, your own post adds a PBR rule, and the system always has 3 built-in PBR rules, so I really doubt that you have a completely empty ip rule output, especially after doing an ip rule add like in the post.
